# SQL EXCEPT performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, except

I'm trying to use a query similar to the following query to find differences between two tables (the same table in a DEV database vs a TEST database).  Each table has ~30K rows and ~5 columns.

```
select field1,field2,field3,field4,field5 from dev.dbo.table1 
where field1+field2 in ('string1','string2','string3',...,'string50')
except
select field1,field2,field3,field4,field5 from test.dbo.table1 
where field1+field2 in ('string1','string2','string3',...,'string50')
```

field1 is `char(5)` and field2 is `char(1)`

This query essentially never terminates.

When i analyze this query using `SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON`, I can see there is a nested loop pretty high in the tree.  When I change the above query to

```
select * from dev.dbo.table1 
except
select * from test.dbo.table2
```

The query runs quickly and there is no nested loop in the execution plan.

Can someone help explain this?  I don't understand why there would be a drastic difference.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My best guess is that the optimizer is doing a poor job of estimating the cardinality (size) of the two tables.  Because it underestimates the size, it is generating a poor query plan.

In SQL Server, you can use `join` hints on `except`.  So, you can get the query you want with:

```
select field1,field2,field3,field4,field5 from dev.dbo.table1 
where field1+field2 in ('string1','string2','string3',...,'string50')
except
select field1,field2,field3,field4,field5 from test.dbo.table1 
where field1+field2 in ('string1','string2','string3',...,'string50')
option (hash join, merge join)
```

This eliminates the option of the nested loop join, choosing a more favorable method.

Comment: I have confirmed that this is exactly the case.  The same query when executed against other databases does not suffer from nested loops, so the fault seems to lie with SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

Your first query is slow because you are concatonating fields, which is essentially a function, in the where clause.  This happens pretty much all the time you run functions in a where clause.  Here is a simpler example.  This will be quick.

```
where myDateTimeField >= @DateValue
and myDateTimeField < dateadd(day, 1, @DateValue)
```

This is logically the same, but will be slow

```
where cast(myDateTimeField as date) = @DateValue
```

Comment: Thanks, I selected table1 into a temp table in both databases with the additional column field1+field2, changed the query to use temp tables, and that solves my problem as well

Answer (score 1):

I will write this answer for those are interested in, I know this is almost 10yrs old topic, but I faced this question myself I can't find answer at all.

Yep it's the case, what I will recommend is to use
`INNER JOIN` And not the `EXCEPT`
code will look a bit bigger, but performance worth it.

Here is my solution
Before:

```sql
SELECT 
t1.a,
t1.b
FROM @Tabl1 t1

EXCEPT

SELECT 
t2.a,
t2.b
FROM @Tabl2 t2
```

Performance on Tables with more that 1k records was just terrible.
[Performance of EXCEPT keyword in SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/La1sZ.png)

Here is what I came with

```sql
SELECT 
    t1.a,
    t1.b,
    t1.c,
    t1.d
FROM @StoreConfig t1
JOIN  (SELECT  
        t2.a,
        t2.b,
        t2.c,
        t2.d
FROM Table2 t2 ON 
    t2.a= t1.a AND t2.b = t1.b AND( t2.c <> t1.c OR t2.d <> t1.d)
```

Here is the performance increase (Notice, without last Select all request take about 1s, so this join only takes 0.01 - 0.3s not the whole 4 seconds.

[Performance with JOIN statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c20WI.png)