# SQL (NOT IN) Query takes forever to execute

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have a query which takes more than 2 hrs to execute for million records, I am not sure how I can optimize it to make it run little faster. [Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b14eb/56) is the sql fiddle for the table and the query.

```
WITH frm 
     AS (SELECT product_id                               AS PId, 
                Min(Cast(product_startdate AS DATETIME)) AS PStartDate 
         FROM   products 
         WHERE  product_status IN ( 'F', 'R', 'M' ) 
         GROUP  BY product_id), 
     firstcount 
     AS (SELECT pid, 
                pstartdate, 
                (SELECT Count(*) 
                 FROM   products 
                 WHERE  product_id IN ((SELECT product_id 
                                        FROM   products 
                                        WHERE  product_status IN ( 'OR', 'OP' ) 
                                               AND product_comments LIKE 
                                                   '%CANCELLED%' 
                                        EXCEPT 
                                        (SELECT product_id 
                                         FROM   products 
                                         WHERE  product_status = 'DE' 
                                         UNION 
                                         SELECT product_id 
                                         FROM   products 
                                         WHERE  product_status = 'OR' 
                                                AND product_comments NOT LIKE 
                                                    '%CANCELLED%')) 
                                       EXCEPT 
                                       (SELECT product_id 
                                        FROM   products 
                                        WHERE  product_status IN ( 
                                               'RE', 'C', 'S', 'D' ) 
                                       )) 
                        AND product_id = pid) AS v_count 
         FROM   frm), 
     secondcount 
     AS (SELECT pid, 
                pstartdate, 
                CASE 
                  WHEN v_count = 0 THEN (SELECT Count(*) 
                                         FROM   products 
                                         WHERE  product_id IN 
                  ( 
                  SELECT product_id 
                  FROM   [dbo].products 
                  WHERE 
                                                product_status IN ( 'F', 
                                                'R', 'M' ) 
                                                AND product_startdate != 
                                                    '.' 
                                                               EXCEPT 
                                                               (SELECT 
                  product_id 
                                                                FROM   products 
                                                                WHERE 
                                                product_status = 'DE' 
                                                                UNION 
                                                                SELECT 
                  product_id 
                                                                FROM   products 
                                                                WHERE 
                                                product_status = 'OR' 
                                                AND product_comments NOT 
                                                    LIKE '%CANCELLED%') 
                                                               EXCEPT 
                                                               (SELECT 
                  product_id 
                                                                FROM   products 
                                                                WHERE 
                                                product_status IN ( 'OR', 
                                                'OP' ) 
                                                AND product_comments LIKE 
                                                    '%CANCELLED%' 
                                                                EXCEPT 
                                                                (SELECT 
                  product_id 
                                                                 FROM   products 
                                                                 WHERE 
                                                 product_status = 
                                                 'DE' 
                                                                 UNION 
                                                SELECT product_id 
                                                FROM   products 
                                                WHERE  product_status = 
                                                       'OR' 
                                                       AND product_comments NOT 
                                                           LIKE '%CANCELLED%')) 
                                                               EXCEPT 
                                                               (SELECT 
                  product_id 
                                                                FROM   products 
                                                                WHERE 
                                                product_status IN ( 'RE', 
                                                'C', 'S', 'D' ))) 
                                                AND product_id = pid) 
                  ELSE v_count 
                END AS v_count 
         FROM   firstcount) 
INSERT INTO products_del 
            (product_id, 
             product_startdate, 
             productdel_status) 
SELECT pid, 
       pstartdate, 
       CASE 
         WHEN v_count != 0 THEN 'UNKNOWN' 
         ELSE NULL 
       END 
FROM   secondcount 

SELECT * 
FROM   products_del
```

Comment: Please post it here with the explain analyze, rather than on jsfiddle.

Comment: Put some indexes on that table - look at the execution plan, it's table scan after table scan.

Comment: It might be helpfull if you explain your table structure and explain what you want to achieve. It is up to YOU, making US understand your target without reverse engineering your query.

Comment: I do not have any indexes on this table. This all data comes from some Rssfeed in a very bad format. We got few stored procedures with this data in PL/SQL. Since we do not have Oracle, my job is trying to convert them in T-SQL. In Oracle it this stored proc executes in less then 3 minutes but in T-SQL more than 2 Hrs

Comment: Common table expressions are very nice to work with but they can slow down complex queries - especially large ones. Try selecting your queries into temporary table (or table variables) instead of nesting common table expressions and see if that helps.

Comment: Even if the table is messy or temporary, the indexes should speed up the query. If taking two hours, the time building them could be a good tradeoff for enhanced query time.

Comment: Correlated subqueries are essentialy cursors, they run row by row not on the whole set. You should not use them in any case where you have a performance issue.

Comment: And if you use a temp table per @AllanS.Hansen you can index it which can really speed things up

Comment: Consider adding join hints to your excepts, to direct the query plan, as described in the first answer, on this SO link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16084350/sql-except-performance/16084805#16084805

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following. I simplified the inner queries by eliminating unnecessary `IN`, `UNION`, and `EXCEPT` clauses.

```
WITH frm 
     AS (SELECT product_id                               AS PId, 
                Min(Cast(product_startdate AS DATETIME)) AS PStartDate 
         FROM   products 
         WHERE  product_status IN ( 'F', 'R', 'M' ) 
         GROUP  BY product_id), 
     firstcount 
     AS (SELECT pid, 
                pstartdate, 
                (SELECT Count(*) 
                 FROM   products 
                 WHERE  product_status IN ( 'OR', 'OP' ) 
                   AND product_comments LIKE '%CANCELLED%' 
                   AND product_id = pid) AS v_count 
         FROM   frm), 
     secondcount 
     AS (SELECT pid, 
                pstartdate, 
                CASE 
                  WHEN v_count = 0 THEN (SELECT Count(*) 
                                         FROM   products 
                                         WHERE  product_status IN ( 'F', 'R', 'M' ) 
                                                AND product_startdate != '.' 
                                                AND product_id = pid) 
                  ELSE v_count 
                END AS v_count 
         FROM   firstcount) 
INSERT INTO products_del 
            (product_id, 
             product_startdate, 
             productdel_status) 
SELECT pid, 
       pstartdate, 
       CASE 
         WHEN v_count != 0 THEN 'UNKNOWN' 
         ELSE NULL 
       END 
FROM   secondcount 

SELECT * 
FROM   products_del
```

Comment: It looks like this would work, if this table has only one row per product (typical for a `products` table).  But if this table allows multiple rows per product, then wouldn't you need to *somehow* code for the exclusions, like `WHERE  product_status = 'DE'`, or `WHERE  product_status IN ('RE', 'C', 'S', 'D' )`?

Comment: ProductId is not uniue here so we need to check for all the status which includes 'DE' and ('RE', 'C', 'S', 'D' ) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b14eb/56